# Using Tableau how to count unique visitors over a user picked time period?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with the following fields:
VENDOR_ID
USER_ID
VISIT_START_DATE_TIME

How do I count distinct visitors over a user defined time period?
So the user might pick, daily, weekly...yearly and the display would show for each Vendor how many unique visitors showed up for that period

So if they pick daily, it would display:

```
    VENDOR   June 20; June 19; June 18;
    ABC Corp     451      350       27
    DEF Inc        4        0        2
```

If they picked yearly it would display:

```
    VENDOR    2019;    2018;    2017
    ABC Corp  3500     1203        0
    DEF Inc     52       20       12
```

The display would only show the most recent 12 periods

Would I have to create a version of the dashboard for each time period? Would it be possible for the user to choose arbitrary time periods (10 days?) and then the column heading would just be the first day of each periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Granularity of the data should be at the Day level so that You can roll up to week, month and Year level in the database. When you are developing your Dashboard (Single dashboard.. no need for multiple), it should  published using Date parameter. Please provide the tool you are using to publish the dashboard or you may search date parameter for the visualization tool.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had tagged this as Tableau. I will add that I am using Tableau as the visualization tool.